# How to generate Python dictionary from OpenAPI 3 YAML file?

Tags: python, api, dictionary, openapi

Is there a Python 3 package or code snippet that can read an OpenAPI 3 YAML file and convert it to a Python dictionary?

This is an example of the contents in an OpenAPI 3 YAML file

```
openapi: 3.0.0
servers:
    url: https://localhost/api
paths:
  /user/{userId}:
    get:
      summary: Get a user by ID
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: userId
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        name:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserFullName'
        age:
          type: integer
    UserFullName:
      type: object
      properties:
        firstName:
          type: string
        lastName:
          type: string
```

I want the package/code to generate a Python dictionary looking something like this

```
{
  "/user/{userId}": {
    "get": {
      "200": {
        "id": "integer",
        "name": {
          "firstName": "string",
          "lastName": "string"
        }
        "age" "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

------ Edit -----

I have tried PyYaml, however, it is not returning what I am expecting.

I am expecting the '$ref' key-value pair to act as a string interpolation like this:

```
{
   "id":0,
   "name":{
      "firstName":"string",
      "lastName":"string"
   },
   "age":0
}
```

Instead, PyYaml is returning this:

```
{
  "id":0,
  "name": {
    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/UserFullName"
  },
  "age":0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a package called `pyyaml`.
To know more please refer to this article [How to Read YAML File to Dict in Python](https://fedingo.com/how-to-read-yaml-file-to-dict-in-python/)

Comment: Thank you, I have added clarification to the question after using PyYaml